# Capture two digit pairs from a text

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to capture all two digits from the following header file:

```
#define KEYMAP( \
    K00, K01, K02, K03, K04, K05, K06, K07, K08, K09, K0A, K0B, K0C, K0D, \
    K10, K11, K12, K13, K14, K15, K16, K17, K18, K19, K1A, K1B, K1C, K1D, \
    K20, K21, K22, K23, K24, K25, K26, K27, K28, K29, K2A, K2B, K2C, K2D, \
    K30, K31, K32, K33, K34, K35, K36, K37, K38, K39, K3A, K3B, K3C, K3D, \
    K40, K41, K42,           K45,                K49, K4A, K4B, K4C, K4D  \
)
```

So I want to get a list containing 00,01,02.....4D. I tried to do this using the `Select-String` cmdlet:

```
gc 'y:\keyboard.h' | sls 'K'
```

But doesnt give me the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the static [regex::Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
$content = Get-Content 'y:\keyboard.h' -Raw
[regex]::Matches($content, '\bK(..),') | Foreach {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

**Output:**

> 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
>   19 1A 1B 1C 1D 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 30 31 32 33
>   34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 40 41 42 45 49 4A 4B 4C

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookbehind assertion in the pattern and a proper hexadecimal capturing pattern (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iT2mB6/1)):

```ps
gc 'y:\keyboard.h' | select-string '(?<=K)([\da-f]{2})' -AllMatches | %{ $_.matches.value }
```

`Select-String` uses case-**in**sensitive matching by default, use its `-CaseSensitive` switch if needed. It's possible to make matching more strict to reject possible false positives from other parts of the file: `'\s+(?<=K)([\da-fA-F]{2})(?:[\s,]|$)' -CaseSensitive`